# How to display a photo to Organization Chart? SharePoint 2013

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I have a list like following: [image]

and I have an organization chart based on this list:[image]

I need above the name to be displayed an Image from `Publishing Image` and it is also `Publishing Image` column type  how can I display It.

Here is my code: I am using google charts with C# and i need image to be with 100x60px

```
public partial class OrganizationChartUserControl : UserControl
{
    //Get the List name to fetch the data from
    string listName = "OrgChart_Demo";
    int iRowCounter = 0;
    string sAllNewRows = string.Empty;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Fetch the data (recursively) from the list
        GetNode(string.Empty);

        //Generate the Client Script and Register
        GenerateClientScript(sAllNewRows);
    }

    private void GenerateClientScript(string sAllNewRows)
    {
        string csName1 = "OrgChartScript";
        Type csType = this.GetType();

        ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

        // Check to see if the startup script is already registered. 
        if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(csType, csName1))
        {
            StringBuilder cstext = new StringBuilder();
            cstext.Append("<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>");
            cstext.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
            cstext.Append("google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['orgchart'] });");
            cstext.Append("google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);");

            cstext.Append("function drawChart() {");
            cstext.Append("var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();");

            cstext.Append("data.addColumn('string', 'Name');");
            cstext.Append("data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');");
            cstext.Append("data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');");
            cstext.Append("var rowArr = new Array();");

            cstext.Append(sAllNewRows);

            cstext.Append("data.addRows(rowArr);");

            cstext.Append("var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));");
            cstext.Append("chart.draw(data, { allowHtml: true, allowCollapse: true });");
            cstext.Append("}");
            cstext.Append("</script>");
            cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, csName1, cstext.ToString(), false);

        }

    }

    private void GetNode(string reportsTo)
    {
        SPListItemCollection itemCol = GetListItems(listName, reportsTo);

        foreach (SPListItem item in itemCol)
        {
            //create a new row
            sAllNewRows += createNewRow(item);

            //Recursion
            GetNode(item["Name"].ToString());
        }

    }

    private string createNewRow(SPListItem listItem)
    {
        string sName = ConvertTo.CastIn<string>(listItem["Name"]);
        string sTitle = ConvertTo.CastIn<string>(listItem["Title"]);
        string sMoreInfo = ConvertTo.CastIn<string>(listItem["MoreInfo"]);
        string sReportsTo = ConvertTo.CastIn<string>(listItem["ReportsTo"]);

       // string sReportsTo = new SPFieldLookupValue(ConvertTo.CastIn<string>(listItem["ReportsTo"])).LookupValue;

        StringBuilder sText = new StringBuilder();
        sText.Append("var NewRow = new Array();");
        sText.Append(String.Format("NewRow.push({{ v: '{0}', f: '{1}<div style=\"color:red; font-style:italic\">{2}</div>' }});", sName, sName, sTitle));
        sText.Append(String.Format("NewRow.push('{0}');", sReportsTo));
        sText.Append(String.Format("NewRow.push('{0}');", sMoreInfo));
        sText.Append(String.Format("rowArr[{0}] = NewRow;", iRowCounter));

        iRowCounter++;
        return sText.ToString();
    }

    private SPListItemCollection GetListItems(string destList, string reportsTo)
    {
        SPListItemCollection ResultListItems = null;

        using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = oWeb.Lists.TryGetList(destList);
                if (null == list)
                    return ResultListItems;

                //Check if the item already exist.
                StringBuilder sCAMLQuery = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
                sCAMLQuery.Append("<Where>");
                if (reportsTo != string.Empty)
                {
                    sCAMLQuery.Append("<Eq>");
                    sCAMLQuery.Append("<FieldRef Name='ReportsTo' />");
                  //  sCAMLQuery.Append("<Value Type='Lookup'>" + reportsTo + "</Value>");
                    sCAMLQuery.Append("<Value Type='Text'>" + reportsTo + "</Value>");

                    sCAMLQuery.Append("</Eq>");
                }
                else
                {
                    sCAMLQuery.Append("<IsNull>");
                    sCAMLQuery.Append("<FieldRef Name='ReportsTo' />");
                    sCAMLQuery.Append("</IsNull>");
                }
                sCAMLQuery.Append("</Where>");

                SPQuery QueryResult = new SPQuery();
                QueryResult.Query = sCAMLQuery.ToString();
                ResultListItems = list.GetItems(QueryResult);
            }
        }

        return ResultListItems;
    }
}
```

Please help me.
Thank you!

Comment: Why are you spamming language tags with this question? Doing this makes the question overly broad just by definition.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for your suggestion I thought it would me more famous question :P :)

Comment: Yes, you bring more attention to the question, but most of it will be *unwanted* attention. Please make your tags much more specific.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thank you I fixed my tags. Any answer for question?

Comment: No idea, since I only know Java and your question has nothing to do with Java programming.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels No problem thanks for your attention

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115111/discussion-between-nderon-hyseni-and-hovercraft-full-of-eels).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, it isn't important anymore but for those who will have this problem in the future. The only line that should be changed is this:

`sText.Append(String.Format("NewRow.push({{ v: '{0}', f: '<img src =\"{1}\" style=\"width:57px; height:57px; float:left;\" />{2}<div style=\"color:white; font-style:Arial\">{3}</div>' }});", sName, sPicture, sName, sTitle));`

Thanks goes to @hardik who solved my problem!